# What Java feature(s) historically started as a pattern and is now a language feature?

Tags: java, programming-languages, history

I'll be honest. I need help with a homework question that I'm stumped with.

Describe something that historically started as a pattern and is now supported with 
a language feature in Java.

Comment: I hope you'll do some additional work (the *describing*) to the answers here :-)

Comment: Wow lots of very helpful answers and they came very fast. Thanks a bunch guys!

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for being honest about it being a homework question. :)

Comment: And more proof that SO is not yet as widely-known as it should be. Next target group: teachers

Comment: This is a really really stupid homework for students who want to learn programming, there is no point. The teacher must be a moron.

Comment: Try programmers rather than SO

Comment: Don't understand why this shouldn't be a valid question.

Comment: @Roflcoptr, because it is *not* a programming question. @Aiden Bell is right, programmers.stackexchange.com is better suited

Comment: Then migration would have been better

Comment: "Don't understand why this shouldn't be a valid question." - there is no correct answer and any answer given is subjective.

Comment: @chuck: How did you find this website? Actually, it could easily be something that teachers should recommend. (If you suggest and they object, you might suggest they recommend at the end of your course when you are supposed to already know how to program :P) (Don't take me too seriously)

Answer (score 46):

They're probably looking for `enum`s.

Before Java 1.5 introduced language support for `enum`s, standard practice was to define a set of `public static final int`s as enum values.
This pattern can be seen all over Swing.

Many of these constants are defined in interfaces so that classes can implement the interface and use the constants without a qualifying typename; the [`SwingConstants` interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingConstants.html) is a great example.

Comment: Swing even uses strings as many of the magic constants.

Comment: +1: but you should also add that Java's built-in enum support is an (somewhat less powerful) implementation of the [Typesafe enum pattern](http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/enum.html).

Comment: Swing does in places actually manage to use the "type-safe enum pattern" with an enum-like class. For example `HTML.Tag` in Swing text. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTML.Tag.html

Comment: Really? Java only had enums in 1.5? Wow, Java was an amazingly backwards language before 2004...

Comment: @rsenna: Yeah, it's effectively just a bit of compiler magic, ;).
@configurator: I know, I'm just glad I stepped into Java when it reached the 1.5 version. Particularly for the generics, without those, it'd be type safety hell. (imo)

Answer (score 42):

The most obvious pattern I can think of around that is iterating via `Iterable<T>` and `Iterator<T>`, which is now available as a feature via the enhanced for-each loop.

Comment: +1 for being jon skeet. also for a good answer

Answer (score 5):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history: Enumerations (typesafe enum pattern)

More on this pattern in item 21 in Chapter 5 of 'Effective Java' (found here: http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter5.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

Annotations are all about metadata that used to stored in a variety of xml files or in javadoc comments now you can use annotations to store metadata with the code.

Dependency injection is another pattern that while not part of the java language is making its way into the core jdk frameworks.

Answer (score 4):

Iterators. They have a special for loop which is translated into hasNext() and next() calls.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Generics. That was not part of Java from the beginning but was implemented from 1.5 and above.

Comment: No; generics did not start as a pattern.

Comment: @roflcoptr, what was the pattern that allowed generics prior to Java 5? I am not aware there was one. Hence the reason why this answer is incorrect.

Comment: Before generics it was necessary to cast all elements in collections etc. This usage pattern was widely used and annoying and that's why Sun implemented Generics in 1.5

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bad answer.  People did all manner of disgusting things to try to enforce invariants on their collections before generics, from Javadoc comments to runtime type checking to extending `ArrayList` and overloading methods like `add()` to take only the desired type, etc.

Comment: @Voji: That's what I meant to say.  I'm asking what @rofl means.

Comment: I used to put generic notation /*<commented out>*/ on variable declarations.

Comment: @SLaks: Yeah, I just realized that, so I removed my comment. Lesson learned: I shouldn't comment on Internet while I'm bored with a teleconference meeting...

Answer (score 1):

enums.........................

Comment: I'd have been quicker if I hadn't had to go through 3 iterations of making it 30 characters long and doing the captchas... :-/

Comment: Add a link to http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html and you get the 30 characters...

Answer (score 1):

Observer/Observable which is the "Observer[GOF]" pattern from the gang of four... : http://www.exciton.cs.rice.edu/JavaResources/DesignPatterns/book/hires/pat5gfso.htm

`Comparator<T>` which is the "Strategy[GOF]" pattern also from the gang of four : http://www.exciton.cs.rice.edu/JavaResources/DesignPatterns/book/hires/pat5ifso.htm

And many more !

Answer (score 0):

[Performance.](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation)

Comment: How did that start out as a pattern? Also, it's not a **language** feature.

Comment: Wait; Java is performant? When did that happen?

Comment: @SLaks, people used to worry about performance and used performant patterns to write their code. Now it's a feature of the JVM, arguably built into the language... or some other justification for my sarcastic answer :P

Answer (score 0):

(Oops. I am sorry. Always thought C++ templates have something to do with the pattern. I was wrong)

<<<<< Ignore the following lines >>>>>

Not sure if I am right but let me take a shot.

Java Generics are roughly based on Template pattern

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88913.aspx
(Link is on C# generics though)

Comment: Templates are a C++ language feature, not a design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

There haven't been many **language** features added which appear in the JLS.

Perhaps you could argue that the @Override supports the pattern of overriding/implementing methods by detecting when a method was inteded to override a parent's method/implement an interface method but does not.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html search for @Override

Answer (score 0):

I noticed no one mentioned Prototype (clone) and Momento (Serializable).